# Random order of a subset or results in QuerySet in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I've a query like this:

`Listing.objects.all().order_by('-premium', 'title')`

It works like expected, returns all premium classes first and then everything ordered by title.

Now I need to randomize only the order of the `premium` results. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think there's no solution in a single query.
So I've solved this using two queries:

```
premium_results = Listing.objects.filter(premium=True).order_by('?')
normal_results = Listing.objects.filter(premium=False).order_by('title')

results = list(premium_results) + list(normal_results)
```

Note: I needed a list as output, otherwise you can combine queries results using Django's `Q` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can again use `order_by` to sort on `title` without `premium`

```
qs=Listing.objects.filter().order_by('-premium', 'title')
qs2 = qs.order_by('title') # will be sorted on 'title' not 'premium'
```

Or shortcut

```
Listing.objects.filter().order_by('-premium', 'title').order_by('title')
```

Note: I'm using `filter()` instead of `all()` as initial set.

Comment: This way you're ordering by title in the second `order_by`. I need to randomize only premium results, not the rest.